# Don't understand result of java program

Tags: java, sax

I ant to study this code for another application. But i have a problem with the "characters".
Here the code :

```
package tp1;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author jgmorenof
 */
class DeathOf extends DefaultHandler {

    String node = null;
    String contenu = null;
    String titre = null;
    String motif = "death of";

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        node = qName;
        if (node.equals("title") || node.equals("text")) {
            contenu = "";
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (node != null && node.equals("title")) {
            //System.out.println(contenu);
            titre = contenu;
            //System.out.println("\t\tTitre : " + titre);
        }

        if (node != null && node.equals("text")){
            annotate(contenu);
        }
        node = null;
        contenu = null;
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        if (node != null && (node.equals("title") || node.equals("text"))) {
            contenu += new String(ch, start, length);
            System.out.println(contenu);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            parser.parse("simplewiki-20161001-pages-articles.xml", new DeathOf());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void annotate(String contenu) {
        String pattern = motif+" [A-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]+ [A-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]+";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(contenu);
        if (m.find( )) {
            for(int i=0;i<=m.groupCount();i++)
                System.out.println("Personne: " + m.group(i).replace(motif,"") );
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the result of "characters" after my "system.out.println(contenu)". I'm not confortable with the SAX either. 
Can anyone explain me the public void characters? why contenu is not ampty anymore ? From where 'ch, start, lentgh' are comming from ?

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#characters-char:A-int-int- So basically, the SAX Parser notifies this handler of character data. ch, start and length come from the parser.

Comment: You should look at the documentation of `String(char[], int, int)`

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, a SAX parser works by calling methods back in your class. That is the reason why that class implements the DefaultHandler interface.

And those public methods, *startElement*, *endElement*, and *[characters](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#characters(char[],%20int,%20int))* are therefore called by the SAX parser while doing its work!

And you know, you **wrote** those methods, so you should know what they are doing!

But well:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
```

As said: the SAX parser implementation is **calling** that method - and it is using values corresponding to the content of your XML file!

Then:

```
  if (node != null && (node.equals("title") || node.equals("text"))) {
        contenu += new String(ch, start, length);
```

The above creates a new String value ... and **appends** that to *contenu*.

In other words: that field *contenu* changes ... because the code says it should be changed.

Seriously: if you don't understand such basic things; then don't engage in XML parsing yet. Instead, step back and learn about **basics** of Java.

And if you wish to understand what is going on: simply put print statements in each of the public methods (that also print the parameters given to each of the method) ... and you will quickly see in which order and with what parameters the SAX parser is calling those methods!

Comment: I didn't wrote it, it's my professor.
Thank you for you answer @GhostCat ! I will also go see the documentation :)

Comment: Hint: when learning things ... make experiment. Dont start with asking other people, work on your curiosity to **try** things yourself. And: before going out to strangers; try talking to your peers or your teachers. But glad I could be helping.

Comment: I had already understood why contenu changes, you sad it : it's basic progrmmation ! My question was maybe not enough clear. I just did'nt understand from where ch, start and length come from. and that because I never saw or use the SAX.
Oh and I already did the print statement in each of the public methods this let me see the content of "contenu" and make me ask the question.
I asked a question, you know just for help to understand hat y professor did, and even if i never sa the SAX package I have to now so the step back is not something i could do.
Anyway thank you, you look condescending

Comment: Didnt want to be rude; so sorry if I did. Maybe not the best day today.

Comment: no problem, there is someday like this...just courage. Wish you best and thank you again.